# How to install Angular?

Tags: angular

I have the folder for angular angular-cli-12.1.0-next.5 on my laptop I cannot using the regular method for install using npm install -g @angular/cli, what should I do to install Angular from this folder?

Answer (score 0):

Provide the folder to the npn install command:

```
npm install /path
```

Answer (score 0):

Provide the folder path:

```
npm install -g {angular_folder_path}
```

`-g` will install this globally.